# bing and google think VM is in Taiwan

Tags: azure

I just created a bunch of new vm. My Network, Affinity group, Storage, and vm region is set to US East. when i go to Googleor bing from these vm, it think that i am in Taiwan. My gateway ip and vm public ip is showing in Brazil. This is very annoying. .
I am setting up vm for RDS. Once the users start using it. It will be challenging to explain o uses why their browser is directing to Taiwan's Google or bing.

1. Is there a way to make force browses to use US region regardless of IP address location?
2. Is it possible to force all traffic through site-to-site VPN, ? All traffic including internet traffic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Microsoft recently acquired a large number of IP addresses from LACNIC the regional registry that handles the Latin America area. According to their datacenter IP list (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) they made these new addresses available to be used in most locations. In an odd twist the only addresses ranges in the Brazil region happened to be from ARIN (North American regional registry) (https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml).

It is an annoyance but there isn't much they can probably do. Most of the regional registries are running out of IPv4 address space they probably need them. They aren't routing them through incorrect regions or anything so not to worry your VM's are in the correct places.

Now some companies that purposely use GEO IP databases to limit or restrict traffic (not really a good idea honestly) might have issues if for some reason they block traffic to IP ranges that IT administrators don't 'approve of.'

Realistically this is just a side effect of slow IPv6 adoption. Chances are Microsoft isn't going to be the only ones having to do this in the coming years.

Anyway, try to shutdown and restart your machine again and you have a chance to get IP in other region.

In order to route internet traffic through point-to-site vpn, you need to configure a NAT router on a VM in the azure virtual network however NAT router configurations are typically with 2 NICs while multiple NICs are not supported on an Windows Azure Virtual Machine.